# Can I combine the power of 2 solar panels with 12V dc barrel jacks?

Tags: 12v, solar-energy

I have two solar panels that both output to a 12V DC barrel jacks. 
I want to feed them into a power bank that has a female jack. 
Is there some way to feed the power of both panels to the input?
Would it suffice to use a barrel plug splitter with 2 female jacks?

Comment: No because the panels may start to charge each other if they don't have identical voltages.

Comment: Use diodes on both panels and you'd be fine.

Comment: I just saw in the specs that the panels have integrated blocking diodes. So I guess a simple dc splitter cable should work as long as it is rated for the combined amps of the panels.

Answer (score 2):

The splitter should give acceptable results if both panels have the same output voltage (ie: both are the same model and both get about the same amount of sunlight at the same time).

If they aren't evenly matched the weaker solar panel may leech energy from the system - such that just using the single better solar panel could be more efficient. series diodes on each would prevent that but reduce output by about 5% from just using the single panel.

To determine what to do you need to make some measurements: connect one panel and measure the voltage on both panels,  the swap panels and measure again, if in both cases the unconnected panel has higher voltage the the connected panel there will be some gain to to connecting both panels to the powerbank.

If not there won't,

In cases where the illumination is uneven, (eg: one panel faces east and the other west) then series diodes could help.

But since your panels already have diodes, there's nothing you need to do, just hook them up. there's no way that having two panels connected would be worse than having one.